# MySQL delete trailing question marks

Tags: mysql

I imported data from csv files into a MySQL database, but made the mistake of not
removing the trailing spaces in the csv columns. So the spaces are seen as '?' at 
the end of some values in the database (of type Varchar). I want to get rid of these.
Can I somehow delete all these ?s in the database in one go? I know of the replace 
command, but I think that works on a single column of a singe table at a time, which will
be very time consuming for me. Could anyone please suggest something better? Thanks!

Comment: Use trim function in the update to query to remove begining and trailing spaces

Comment: Why are the spaces being seen as question marks? That sounds like you may have some kind of character encoding issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [trim](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function

```
UPDATE table SET column = TRIM(TRAILING '?' FROM column)
```

Comment: You are right, but is there any way to delete ALL trailing ?s in the DATABASE, instead of trimming each column in each table separately?

Comment: The only way is to query information_schema and make script that iterates trough all of tables and trim all of the columns. Better, fix your import script and reimport the data.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll reimport the data after fixing it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I used your solution finally, so I am accepting it. Thanks again!